# Playing a sound from local Documents

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm trying to get a mp3 from the local Documents on the phone. But I can't get it to work.

If I add the mp3 directly like this to the project it works.

```
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound" ofType:@"mp3"]];
```

But lets say i have the Sound.mp3 in Documents I tried with this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *strPointSound = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"/tours/media/%@", self.point.pointSound] ];


NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:strPointSound ofType:@"mp3"]];
```

self.point.pointSound is "Sound.mp3".

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:strPointSound ofType:@"mp3"]];`

to

`NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPointSound];`

Because the Document folder is not a part of your bundle, so you do not need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it

```
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPointSound];
```